# Печать документов с google диск

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-cloud

---

Есть скрипт формирования документов в google диск в определённую папку:

```
// Создаём и заполняем АКТ
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1i_oEeevF4z8IMsnTGytWnNhUFiXsLkeJbeRMDWawzVM");
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1AD3LaXAVOE4RiRWo51gVT6bIp2R5HHaO");
 var aktid = file.makeCopy("3.Акт Вода - "+ i,folder).getId();
 var docakt = DocumentApp.openById(aktid);
 docakt.editAsText().replaceText("#НОМЕР АКТА#", "№ 120"+('0' + (datastart.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +"-"+ i);
 docakt.editAsText().replaceText("#Фамилия Имя Отчество#", newfio);
 Logger.log(docakt.getText());
 docakt.saveAndClose();
```

Пытаюсь автоматизировать печать всех сформированных за день файлов через google cloud print.

Нашёл в сети такое: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget

Вопрос: как прописать код для кнопки "напечатать все документы"?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: а вопрос-то в чём состоит? уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вопрос в задании. Как всегда, мимо правил.
Основное направление - печатайте по API Cloud Print. Там две строки кода. А через год вам придется либо покупать сервис типа CRUD либо поднимать свой. Но код на скриптах не поменяется.

Answer (score 0):

Прикладываю решение:

Заполняйте свои значения в var 
Разворачивайте скрип для web
Так же предусмотрели печать из разных папок.
к ссылке для запуска скрипта в конце дописывайте ?folderid=код папки

```
       function doGet(e) {
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined'){
    var request = JSON.stringify(e.parameter);
    var answer = JSON.parse(request);
    if (DriveApp.getFileById(answer.folderid)) {
      triggerPrint(answer.folderid);    
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("OK!");
    }else {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Данная папка отсутствует на диске. Проверьте правильно ли написан id");
    }
  }
 }
var printerID = '';//ID принтера из Google Cloud Print
var clientId = ''; //ID API OAuth2.0 из console.developers.google.com
var clientSecret = '';//ключ API OAuth2.0 из console.developers.google.com

function triggerPrint(folderid) {
  //Переменные act, temp_act, printerID, clientId, clientSecret определенны в файле config.gs
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  var contents = folders.getFiles();
  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    printGoogleDocument(file.getId(), printerID, file.getName());
    file.setTrashed(true);
    Logger.log(file.getName() + " успешно распечатан!");
  }
}
function showURL() {
  var cpService = getCloudPrintService();
  if (!cpService.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log(cpService.getAuthorizationUrl());
  }
}
function getCloudPrintService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('print')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setClientId(clientId)
    .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint')
    .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}
function authCallback(request) {
  var isAuthorized = getCloudPrintService().handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Теперь Вы можете использовать Google Cloud Print с помощью Apps Script');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Cloud Print Error: Доступ запрещен');
  }
}
function getPrinterList() {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getContentText();
  var printers = JSON.parse(response).printers;
  for (var p in printers) {
    Logger.log("%s %s %s", printers[p].id, printers[p].name, printers[p].description);
  }
}
function printGoogleDocument(docID, printerID, docName) {
    var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR",
        vendor_id: "Color"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      }
    }
  };
    var payload = {
    "printerid" : printerID,
    "title"     : docName,
    "content"   : DriveApp.getFileById(docID).getBlob(),
    "contentType": "application/pdf",
    "ticket"    : JSON.stringify(ticket)
  };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  if (response.success) {
    Logger.log("%s", response.message);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Код ошибки: %s %s", response.errorCode, response.message);
  }
}
function testFirstPrint() {
  var testFileId = '';//ID тестового документа
  var testFileName = 'Тестовый документ';
  printGoogleDocument(testFileId, printerID, testFileName);
  Logger.log(testFileName + " успешно распечатан!");
}
```